# Building executable for linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

how do i make a linux installer from setup.py. I made an .msi from my setup.py file and here is the code for it

```
import cx_Freeze
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Slither.py")]
cx_Freeze.setup(
        name="Slytherine",
        options = {
                      "build_exe": {
                                       "packages":["pygame"],
                                       "include_files": ["apple.png", "snake_head.png", "Score.dll"]
                                   }
                  },
        description = "Snake game",
        executables = executables
        )
```

What changes should be done in order to make a linux installer for it or do i have to build it on a linux machine itself?

Comment: Are you looking for just an executable or an installer?

Comment: preferably an installer but in worst case a executable would also do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux distributions use packages, which are usually deployed in repositories.

So you have two ways of distributing a python app.

- Creating a python package, and uploading it to PyPI, so that users can install it with `pip install yourapplication`.
- Creating linux distribution packages (.deb for debian based, rpm for redhat, ...).

I recommend reading the excellent [Python Packaging user guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/) for understanding how does python packages work.

For linux distribution packages, well that is going to be different for every distribution, but for debian based distributions, have a look at [stdeb](https://github.com/astraw/stdeb) which converts python packages into debian packages.

Comment: Good answer.  As a follow up comment, I'd suggest [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) as a tool for packaging for Linux.